# .net lambda expression and out parameter

Tags: c#, .net

I have a WCF method which returns me an array of custom objects like "users", "roles", or something else, and it has page output. WCF method has out parameter, stored procedure select rows and return total records of all rows(not only selected), than i read return value in out parameter. But there is one problem i call WCF-method in lambda expression:

```
var client = MySvcRef.MySvcClient();
var assistant = FormsAuthenticationAssistant();
var result = assistant.Execute<MySvcRef.UserClass[]>(
   () => client.GetAllUsers(out totalRecords, pageIndex, pageSize),
   client.InnerChannel);
```

what better solution for my example?

Comment: can you clarify what your question or problem is?

Comment: My problem is that out parameters can`t be used in lambda, what should I change in architecture of my wcf or other part?

Comment: It would be much better if you will create a simple code that could be copy-pasned-an-easy-run from VS, so I will be able to help.

Comment: Or at least show the signature of assistant.Execute<MySvcRef.UserClass[]>() method

Comment: Look at this simple code, just copy in VS (console app)
http://pastebin.com/2aQsdsHp

Comment: hm... i think that i know solution, it doesn`t want to get from parent method parameter in child method parameter!
I must declare one more variable, than call method with out parameter of temp variable, than equal this var to parent method out param and return custom value

Comment: Yep, just created this http://screencast.com/t/qbhkPUuol

Comment: i use this code:
static void customMethod(out int total)
        {
            int temp=0;
            var assistant = new FormsAuthenticationAssistant();
            var res = assistant.Execute<MyRole[]>(() => GetAll(GetAllRoles(out temp)));
            total = temp;
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried lambdas with out parameters but normally you just need to declare the variable beforehand:

```
var client = MySvcRef.MySvcClient();
var assistant = FormsAuthenticationAssistant();
var totalRecords;
var result = assistant.Execute<MySvcRef.UserClass[]>(
  ()=>client.GetAllUsers(out totalRecords, pageIndex, pageSize), 
  client.InnerChannel);
```

**Edit**:

Your best bet may by to wrap `GetAllUsers` with a separate class that can use the `out` param:

```
Temp temp = new Temp();

var result = assistant.Execute<MySvcRef.UserClass[]>(()=>temp.GetAllUsers(client, pageIndex, pageSize),client.InnerChannel);
int totalRecords = temp.TotalRecords;

...

class Temp
{
    public int TotalRecords;
    public MySvcRef.UserClass[] GetAllUsers(MySvcClient client, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    { 
        int totalRecords;
        var result = client.GetAllUsers(out totalRecords, pageIndex, pageSize);
        TotalRecords = totalRecords;
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Error 144 Cannot use ref or out parameter 'totalRecords' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression

Comment: hm, try replacing var on "int" or appropriate type

Comment: Provide a code that can be easily run from VS please. That emulates this problem, cos I do have this code and it runs well. http://screencast.com/t/1kgF0zfSYe2i